# Padding missing on one side of scrollable div

Tags: html, css

Take a look at my snippet.
The parent div has a scrollbar and a child div.
Why is the padding (5px) missing on the right side?

```css
#moh
{
  background:red;
  overflow-x:auto;
  width:100px;
  padding:5px; // this padding should be on all 4 sides
}

#moh div
{
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="moh">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

To get the bounty I want to know the reason for the missing padding. Maybe there is a name for this phenomenon. Or may it be a browser bug?

It would be excellent to know the part in the CSS or HTML specification which is responsible for the missing padding. But this is not required to get the bounty (Because I know it's hard to find).

Comment: I believe its because your using a flexbox the padding doesn't add color to the right side of the flexbox because it is a flexbox. I believe the padding makes the flexbox's width +5px so I suggest you use change the width of the flexbox to 100px.

Comment: The padding is applied. I think the problem is the second div have a 500px width and his parent is 100px. If you change the second div to 100px works correctly. If you wanna maintain that size maybe you can remove the padding and use a border: 5px solid red; instead.

Comment: if you want a solution for this, its  easy to do by add some HTML or can also be done with css only, but if you only want to understand why it's happening, then  I need to study again I think as I am stretching my head from last 10 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this can tell. It's hard to explain, but I'll try. Your" moh " div width value is 100px," moh " in the div width value is 500px. The order of items on Pages is normally left to right. If you do not apply overflow, you see the overflowing sections :

```css
#moh {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px; // this padding should be on all 4 sides
}

#moh div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="moh">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there's an overflow from left to right. when you give overflow, The Overflow will be hidden automatically. So where's the overflow ? (left ? right ? ) That's why it will try to hide everything from the overflow, that is, the part that goes out when it doesn't fit. The part he's trying to hide is in the padding, so that part doesn't show up.

I'm sorry if I said anything that would be misunderstood. Maybe I helped you understand a little bit.

Comment: I have given your answer the bounty because it makes clear that the padding on the right side is actually there and the child div is overlaying it.

Answer (score 2):

```css
#moh
    {
    background:red;
    overflow-x:auto;
    width:100px;
    padding:5px;
}

#moh div
{
    /* width:500px; */
    height:50px;
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
<div id="moh">
    <div></div>
</div>
</html>
```

The padding on the right hand side doesn't appear because, the total width of the parent div is `100px(width) + 10px(padding)` while the width for the chid div is explicitly set to `500px`.

Since the chid div is a block level element and width property greater than that of the parent, it will move past the parent element and hide the right border from the parent div.

*Solutions*

- either remove the width attribute in the child div (so it will take full width of the parent)
- or set the width of the parent to at least 500px which is the width of the child element

Answer (score 1):

```css
#wrap
    {
      overflow-x:auto;
      width:100px;
    }

#inner
    {
      background:red;
      padding: 15px;
      width: 500px;
    }

#inner div
    {
      width:500px;
      height:100px;
      background:green;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="inner">
      <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

one solution would be this:
I had to add some more HTML but hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `#moh` is `100px` and the inner div is `500px`. The solution is to set them both to `500px` and wrap them with a 3rd div that is limited to `100px` with `overflow-x`.

```css
#wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100px;
}

#moh {
  background: red;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 5px; // this padding should be on all 4 sides
}

#moh div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="moh">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the html behavior of block element like `DIV` and css `overflow` property.

By default html elements flow from left to right.

**Browsers by Default behavior is -**

- If parent `DIV` have any `width` property (or specific width
  inherited) and no css `overflow` rule is defined, and if child `DIV`
  have defined `width` which is more than the parent can accommodate,
  then it will overflow and will grow beyond the right edge of parent.
- To control how Parent Div will deal with overflowing, css `overflow`
  property can be used. `overflow:hidden` will instruct browser to crop
  the exceeding width div at the edge.
- `overflow-x:auto` will instruct browser that, when child element
  exceeded `width` **beyond the edge** then add scrollbar at `x-axis`.

So, in the example case above, the child div is having greater width than parent and it is exceeding of the parent. And parent div is having `'overflow-x:auto'` rule defined, the scrollbar is appearing upto the edge of parent.

**Since padding is inside the edge of the div, it does not considered.**

If you want to have padding on all side of the parent div.

1. Treat the parent div as a grandparent by adding one more div inside a parent and moving child div in it.

   2. On grandparent div you can add required `padding` and `width`.
      3 On new parent set `width:100%` which will expand to fit in a grandparent and setting `overflow-x:auto`rule will add scrollbar when the child div expand beyond the parent width.

So, the code will be something like -

```css
#moh
{
  background:red;

  width:100px;
  padding:5px; // this padding should be on all 4 sides
}

#moh div
{
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
  background:green;
}

div{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

#moh div.moh-container{
  width:100%;
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- Grand parent Div for padding and width -->
<div id="moh">
<!-- Parent Div  width 100% to fit in grandparent and overflow rule -->
   <div class='moh-container'>
   <!-- child element with exceeding width -->
     <div></div>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Fiddle -

```
https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/471ka569/13/
```